# How to change file extension?

Tags: python, excel, xlsx, xls

I am trying to scrape an '.xlsx' file from the [Tax Foundation](https://taxfoundation.org/facts-figures-2017/) website. Sadly I keep receiving an error message that reads: `Excel cannot open the file '2017-FF-For-Website-7-10-2017.xlsx because the file format or file extension is not valid. verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file`. I did some research and it says the way to fix this is to change the file extension to '.xls' instead of '.xlsx'. Can anyone help?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import os

url = urllib.request.urlopen("https://taxfoundation.org/facts-figures-2017/")

soup = BeautifulSoup(url, from_encoding=url.info().get_param('charset'))

FHFA = os.chdir('C:/US_Census/Directory')

seen = set()
for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    href = link.get('href')
    if not any(href.endswith(x) for x in ['.xlsx']):
        continue

    file = href.split('/')[-1]
    filename = file.rsplit('.', 1)[0]
    if filename not in seen:  # only retrieve file if it has not been seen before
        seen.add(filename)  # add the file to the set
        url = urllib.request.urlretrieve('https://taxfoundation.org/' + href, file)
    print(filename)

print(' ')
print("All files successfully downloaded.")
```

P.S. I know you can download the file, but I am web scraping it to automate a specific process.

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: This statement for loop `if not any(href.endswith(x) for x in ['.xlsx'])` runs one time `for x in ['.xlsx']` and then checks if `href.endswith('xlsx')`. You basically can shorten this with `if not href.endswith('.xlsx')` which is simpler.

Comment: I am using Python 3.6 @TheDetective

Comment: @Vinny thank you for your help!

Comment: This was a well written question. I actually learned a bit from your example and the answers below. Thank you for posting the code so that we can try it on our systems. Well done and Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem was with your `url = urllib.request.urlretrieve('https://taxfoundation.org/' + href, file)` line. If you go to the website and hover over the Excel download button, you'll see there is a much longer link, `https://files.taxfoundation.org/20170710170238/2017-FF-For-Website-7-10-2017.xlsx` (notice the `2017....238`?). So you were never correctly downloading the Excel file. Here's the correct line to do so:

`url = urllib.request.urlretrieve(href, file)`

Everything else was working correctly.

Comment: You're welcome! I did use Vinny's suggestion as well, and it still worked.